# How to rebase patch queue while merging a branch in mercurial using mq?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

In our workflow we are using Mercurial `mq` for our development the `default` branch. However, when we need to merge another branch into the `default`, what is the best practice to apply these patches on top of the merged `default`?

Obvious (ugly) way: pop all patches, merge branch then push all patches and fix all the `.rej` files...

Correct way should be to use `rebase` somehow but not sure what's the correct workflow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think `hg rebase --mq` might do what you want. If not, try this:

```
hg rebase -s qbase -d default
```

Comment: I don't think that will work at all ... --mq makes the command work on the patch repository...I don't need to change the patch queue repository...I need to rebase the mq patches on top of the merge

Answer (score 0):

The rebase command itself is aware of Mercurial Queues, at least in semi-recent versions of Mercurial.

See the [rebase documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension#Features), mention of this feature in the [MQ documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension#Merging_patches_with_new_upstream_revisions), and [somebody's blog post](http://blog.vanaltj.com/2012/12/who-knew-mq-and-rebase-extensions-play.html).

In short, you can rebase applied MQ patches like you would any other set of changes, and rebase is smart enough to make sure they remain as MQ patches afterwards.